# Mac OS Big sur Flutter install error, “Bad state: Future already completed”

Tags: macos, flutter, dart, macos-big-sur

it's showing like this.

```
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Future already completed
#0      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:43:31)
#1      _NativeSocket.startConnect.<anonymous closure>.connectNext.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:678:23)
#2      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1043:14)
#3      _NativeSocket.issueWriteEvent (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1050:12)
#4      _NativeSocket.multiplex (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1071:11)
#5      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168:12)
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds...
```

I totally uninstall flutter from macOS Big Sur. but it's still showing the same result.

Comment: What Dart and Flutter version are you on?

Comment: I used flutter_macos_1.22.4-stable.zip to install

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It looks like the issue is related to antivirus software.

I tried installing from zip but continued running into the exact same issue with any Flutter commands. I had to temporarily disable Avast Security and everything resolved itself.

[Link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70596) to issue on GitHub.

**Update**

Disabling the "Scan Secure Connection" option on the Web Shield lets me keep Avast running without any issue with Flutter.

Comment: Because of above error, I disabled Avast web shield and ran "flutter pub get" in my flutter project and all dependency problem resolved in VScode

Comment: @owen its that means when need to run the app, or flutter related command to run then I need to disable Antivirus every time.

Comment: @mihirpipermitwala I believe it will could any time that you run a command where Flutter attempts to download something from the web that is blocked by your antivirus. The best option is probably to whitelist wherever Flutter is hosting their content, but I just disabled it temporarily and now I'm not having any issues with AV running again.

Answer (score 5):

I use Avast Security and had to switch off both File Shield and Web Shield in order to "flutter upgrade" and "flutter pub get" on my project.

[Switch off these Core Shields if using Avast Security](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbmyr.png)

I imagine will need to do the same to add new dependencies and possibly while building for web which is definitely a pain.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue after upgrade to macos "Big Sur". Also, I have Kaspersky Internet Security. When KIS is disabled I get same issue. But after closing the KIS, command

```
$ flutter doctor
```

works.